# How to divide rows in pandas dataframe parwise

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `test`, looking like the following:

```
Col1  Col2 Col 3
 A      4    6
 A      8    36
 B      1    4
 B      6    8
```

Now, I want to pairwise divide the rows of the dataframe resulting in:

```
Col1  Col2 Col 3
 A      2    6
 B      6    2
```

Hence I want to divide the second of the pair by the first of the pair. I amtrying to use `groupby` but without success.
Anyone a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using `groupby` on the first column and using `nth` to divide

```
g = df.groupby("Col1")
out = g.nth(1).div(g.nth(0)).reset_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

  Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A   2.0   6.0
1    B   6.0   2.0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you always have a pair of rows, you can just try `iloc`:

```
(df.iloc[1::2, 1:]
   .div(df.iloc[::2,1:].to_numpy())
   .assign(Col1=df.iloc[1::2,1])
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the Col1 pair doesn't repeat.

```py
def divide(group):
    # You could also use head(1)/tail(1) and first()/last().
    return group.iloc[-1] / group.iloc[0]

df_ = df.groupby('Col1').apply(divide).reset_index()
```

```
# print(df)

  Col1  Col2  Col3
0    A   2.0   6.0
1    B   6.0   2.0
```